# Comment out multiple lines in vscode with neovim and shift+v

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim, vscodium

In various Jetbrains products with a vim extension, I can use `shift+v` to select multiple lines, then comment or uncomment the selected lines with the Jetbrains `command+/` command. With vscod(ium) + NeoVim, when I perform this same combo of `shift+v`, then `j` or `k` until multiple lines are selected, then `command+/` , it only comments/uncomments the current line of the cursor.

What is the best way to emulate the Jetbrains behavior in vscode (or vscodium)?

I work primarily in macOS.

I am aware of using `^` to go to the beginning of the current line, then `control+v` combined with `j`/`k`, then `shift+i`, etc, but this is far more commands and harder to perform than a simple multiline select and `command+/`, esp. for uncommenting.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @RogerKint I don't. My work pays for Webstorm where it behaves properly, so that's my solution for now.

Comment: I had the same issue, then I found that `control+/` works. It comments/uncomments all selected lines.